# Integración de API en xml a wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xml

Estoy creando un sitio web para gestión de reservas de viajes, hoteles, etc.
El proveedor por así decirlo, me manda unas carpetas con un montón de archivos xsd
diciendo que tengo que hacer una integración de la Api de ellos para la gestión de las reservas y de más, y posteriormente usar su entorno de pruebas.

No consigo encontrar nada al respecto de como hacer esta integración. Me ha enviado junto a los xsd una carpeta con la documentación pero no como integrarlo. ¿Eso va en el HTML, aparte, sustituye el HTML que es a lo que estoy acostumbrado?

Comment: Primero lo primero: lectura sugerida: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_overview.htm Saludos.

Comment: Muy interesante, pero la verdad es que no me aclara mucho. Quiero decir, se lo que es xml, la validación y todo eso, aunque no lo he utilizado nunca porque hasta ahora todo se me limitaba a html, css, javascript, php etc. Quizás encuentre algún tutorial mas enfocado a la practica de integrarlos y no de como se estructura.

Comment: Básicamente te están dando la documentación de su API que recibe XML, esos son los elementos que debes enviar en el request hacia su API, en algún lado de la documentación debe decir. En la actualidad, es muy común encontrar que se envían datos en formato JSON, la idea es exactamente la misma, solo que con XML en lugar de JSON.  Por otro lado, de manera general cuando "no consigues nada al respecto", analiza qué estás buscando, es muy probable que estés utilizando términos ajenos a lo que realmente quieres. Busca "PHP Post XML API". Saludos y éxitos con la misión :D